# MIPS: User Enter Array Size

Tags: arrays, input, size, mips

I recently got an assignment in my MIPS class and am looking for some help.

The question asks for me to allow the user to enter a number 'n'. This number will create an array of size n in which the user will then use to store float data in. An example run would look like:

```
Enter n: 5
Enter a float: 1.2
Enter a float: 3.2
Enter a float: 5.5
Enter a float: 2.99
Enter a float: 4.4
```

If n were 6, then the array would be of 6 and 6 floats would be entered. Is there any way to allow the user to create the array size in this way?

Note: I wouldn't be so hasty to ask, but the book for this class is out of print and costs $300 on amazon (Introduction to RISC Programming), so I am learning without a book at hand. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to use the operating system's services:

- Use `syscall` 4 to print your strings (with `$a0` pointing to the asciiz string to print)
- Use `syscall` 5 to input an integer (the number of items of your array will be returned in `$v0`)
- Use `syscall` 9 to allocate memory in the heap (with `$a0` indicating the number of bytes to allocate) which return in `$v0` the address of the allocated buffer
- Then use `syscall` 6 as many times as you need to input a float (float returned in `$f0`)

A minimal reference of how to use syscalls can be found in the *MARS simulator*

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using MARS and I was not sure about the reference. I'll give this a go. Will get back to check this as answered if I can figure this out a bit.